# While merging 100+ CSV files, how to fill nan in a column if it doesn't exist in "usecol"?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Considering that I have CSV files which looks roughly like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                   'ColB': [80, 75, 70, 65]})
```

I am using the following script which was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70694509/how-to-add-name-of-csv-files-as-values-in-a-column-while-merging-1000-files)

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'path/' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

fields = ['ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC']

first_one = True
for filename in all_files:

    if not first_one: # if it is not the first csv file then skip the header row (row 0) of that file
        skip_row = [0]
    else:
        skip_row = []

# works with this version: '1.3.4'

# combine into one
mode = "w"
header = True
for filename in all_files:
    with pd.read_csv(
        filename,
        engine="python",
        iterator=True,
        chunksize=10_000,
        usecols = fields
    ) as reader:
        for df in reader:
            filename = os.path.basename(filename)
            df["username"] = filename
            df.to_csv("New_File.csv", index=False, mode=mode, header=header)
            mode = "a"
            header = False
```

Most of the files have all three columns, while few of them do not have **ColC**. This will give an error (understandably) which is as follows:

`ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['ColC']`

How can I put nan in `ColC` while keep `columns` list unchanged?

Comment: What does 'all four columns' mean? In *columns* are three names, your example csv file has two columns. Please try to avoid changing your question after answers have been posted.

Comment: Again, my apologies :( all three columns. 
And yes, it will not happen again. Sorry

Comment: In your case changing the question was justified. But now the answers look incomplete and not very usefull.

Comment: Yes, I agree. It was my mistake, I should've posted the question clearly first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one alternative checking the columns beforehand:

```
# (...)
for filename in all_files:
    # Check available columns first
    cols = pd.read_csv(filename, engine='python', nrows=0, header=0).columns
    fields_ = cols.intersection(fields)
    missed = [i for i in fields if i not in cols]
    
    with pd.read_csv(
        filename,
        engine="python",
        iterator=True,
        chunksize=10_000,
        header=0,
        usecols = fields_  # Use the "dynamic" one
    ) as reader:
        for df in reader:
            # Manually append missed cols
            if missed:
                 for col in missed:
                    df[col] = np.nan

                # Make sure the order is kept
                df = df[fields]

            # (proceed...)

            filename = os.path.basename(filename)
            df["username"] = filename
# (...)
```

Comment: Dear @fsl, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the problem still remains :( , although it makes sense what you did here. But it is giving the same error I dont know why

Comment: Are you passing the modifield `fields_` instead of `fields` to `usecols`?

Comment: Yes, exactly ```usecols = fields_``` like this

Comment: Are you getting the very same error? `Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['ColC']`?

Comment: Yes, the same error.

Comment: Can you triple check this? Makes no sense to miss the column if you're passing the exact ones. Step into the error and make sure `fields != fields_` when it breaks.

Answer (score 2):

If the use of 'usecols' is not a necessity, you could achieve this by using .reindex() instead of 'usecols' like so:

```
columns = ['Col1','ColB','ColC']
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv').reindex(columns=columns)
```

Output

```
  Col1  ColB  ColC
0    A    80   NaN
1    B    75   NaN
2    C    70   NaN
3    D    65   NaN
```

Comment: Nice solution if `usecols=` isn't necessary to select columns from the csv file.

Comment: I was wrong, your solution even works with extra columns. Sorry, I should have tested it before claiming a limitation. `usecols=` would only save computations.

Answer (score 1):

Changed your example columns list to have multiple missing columns. But without changing *columns* in the solution using an augmented example file.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

columns = ['Col1','ColB','ColC','ColD']
try:
    df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',usecols=columns)
except ValueError as e:
    if 'Usecols' not in str(e): raise e
    missing = re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", str(e))
    df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', usecols=set(columns) - set(missing))
    df[missing] = np.nan
df
```

Output

```
  Col1  ColB  ColC  ColD
0    A    80   NaN   NaN
1    B    75   NaN   NaN
2    C    70   NaN   NaN
3    D    65   NaN   NaN
```

---

Creating an example csv file with extra and missing columns

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                   'ColB': [80, 75, 70, 65],
                   'ColE': [100, 20, 1, 23]})
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

test.csv

```
Col1,ColB,ColE
A,80,100
B,75,20
C,70,1
D,65,23
```